# Android build: use "mm" to build 1 C file to 2 executables

Tags: android

I have a C file like the following, which is built into 2 executables, test0 and test1. However, the foo.c is not built for the test1 though it has different flag when I use "mm" and "mm -B" is OK. Is this a bug?

foo.c
    #ifdef TEST1
       ...
    #else
       ...
    #endif

The makefile is like this.
Android.mk

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)
##### build for test 0 ####
include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := foo.c
LOCAL_MODULE := test0
    ...
include $(BUILD_EXECUTABLE)

##### build for test 1 ####
include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := foo.c
LOCAL_MODULE := test1
LOCAL_CFLAGS := TEST1
    ...
include $(BUILD_EXECUTABLE)
##### end of Android.mk ##########
```

Comment: Perhaps not the most elegant solution, but what if you add something like `@touch -c foo.c` prior to `include $(BUILD_EXECUTABLE)` for test1?

Answer (score 0):

You need to define TEST in the LOCAL_CFLAGS using -D. This is standard compile ( gcc ) behaviour, The build for test 1 fragment should look like this

```
##### build for test 1 ####
include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := foo.c
LOCAL_MODULE := test1
LOCAL_CFLAGS := -DTEST1
...
include $(BUILD_EXECUTABLE)
```

Touching the file is not required as Android compiles the object files to an intermediate directory found in the out directory tree, so in this case they will be named as follows

out/target/product/[PRODUCT_DEVICE]/obj/EXECUTABLES/test0_intermediates
out/target/product/[PRODUCT_DEVICE]/obj/EXECUTABLES/test1_intermediates